# Show GitLab job in the pipeline when another job contains 'only'

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to set up `.gitlab-ci.yml` pipeline so that some jobs are executed everywhere (without only and except) and some, like the Deploy step, only on the master branch. But when I add to Deploy `only:`, my other Jobs become invisible if the `only:` property is not specified for them. For example - `Test` job will be hidden everywhere.

Is there a way to configure GitLab to show Test job anywhere without only/except configuration?

```yml
---
stages:
  - Tests
  - Build
  - Deploy

Test:
  stage: Tests

Build:
  stage: Build
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests

Deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  only:
    - master
```

Desired Jobs visibility in the pipelines:

- working branch (and any other pipelines): `Tests`
- merge requests: `Tests`, `Build`
- master branch: `Tests`, `Build`, `Deploy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is due to pipelines for merge requests being created for your project with .

The pipeline you're observing with your jobs missing is the *merge request pipeline*. Only jobs with `only: - merge_requests` will run in the *merge request pipeline*.

You'll notice there is *also* a branch pipeline in your pipeline lists which probably runs more or less as you expect. However, this pipeline won't be displayed in the merge request UI -- in the MR UI, only the *merge request pipeline* is considered.

To fix this, you can add `the following to the Test job:

```yaml
Test:
  # ...
  only:
    - pushes
    - schedules
    - api
    - web
    - triggers
    - merge_requests # enable pipelines for merge requests
```

Or more simply using `rules:`

```yaml
Test:
  rules: # enable pipelines for merge requests
    - when: on_succes
```

If you want to keep using pipelines for merge requests and avoid usage of `only`/`except` on the Test job, you would need to use `rules:` instead. There is no way to avoid configuring the test job for this in *some* way when using pipelines for merge requests.

Alternatively, you can avoid configuring the `Test` job if you can avoid the pipeline for merge requests feature and use `rules:` (or equivalent `only`/`except`) to get the behavior you want, with some caveats.

```yaml
include: # disable pipelines for merge requests
  - template: 'Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml'

Test:
  stage: test
  # ...

Build:
  rules: # run when merge requests are open
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: on_success
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success  # run when on default branch
    - when: never # otherwise, do not run

Deploy:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

Caveats: for the `CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` rule to catch, the merge request must exist before the pipeline is started or must be triggered after the MR is created. This obviously also precludes use of merge request pipeline features.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. Now I use combination of `only:` - for imported Jobs and `rules:` with variables for my own Jobs.